# SplashScreen not changed while changing the orientation in Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, orientation

I tried to set two splash screen for landscape and Portrait. For that, I wrote below code in my activity class

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.equipsplashscreen);
            Log.d("Orientation", "Landscape");
        }
        else {
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);
            Log.d("Orientation", "Portrait");
        }
```

screens are displayed according to the orientation, but the problem is.. screens are not changed while loading(i.e I launched my app in portrait mode, while loading the splash screen I changed the orientation from portrait to landscape, at that time my landscape image was not loading.. only portrait image changed as landscape style ).

I am using cordova-1.8.0 and jquery-1.7.1

How can I do this.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

In Android we have to override the onConfigurationChanged method like this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        init();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        init();
    }
}
```

And adding one tag in Manifest like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" />
```

Now check the requirements in phonegap because i don't know phone gap I give you the tip what had done in android.